"Android: Keeping Bottom Buttons Visible in TabLayout Fragment While Scrolling RecyclerViews"
I have a layout in my Android app that consists of a TabLayout with ViewPager2 and bottom buttons. Within one of the tabs, I have multiple RecyclerViews. The issue I'm encountering is that when I populate the RecyclerViews with data, the tab layout does not scroll, causing the bottom buttons to become obscured by the RecyclerView items.
this is my tablayout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout" />

    <!-- Bottom buttons container -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/border_btn_cancel"
            android:text="انصراف"
            android:textColor="@color/app_black" />

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/border_btn_ok"
            android:text="ثبت"
            android:textColor="@color/app_black" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

and this is my tab1:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

    <!-- Card 1 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/cunsumerGoods"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nab_border_consumer_goods"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addConsumerButton"
        style="@style/MenuButtonsSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="اجناس مصرفی"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
      android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/app_black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
       />

</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:background="#7BA5C6"
            android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="واحد:"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:id="@+id/unitName"
                android:textColor="@color/app_black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="تعداد:"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:id="@+id/countName"

                android:textColor="@color/app_black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="نام"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/textName"
                android:textColor="@color/app_black"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- List items -->
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listConsumerContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/StolenGoods"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nab_border_stolen_goods"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cunsumerGoods"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addStolenButton"
        style="@style/MenuButtonsSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="اجناس سرقتی"
        android:textColor="@color/app_black"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:background="#C48389"
            android:id="@+id/linear2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="واحد:"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/unitName1"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/app_black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="تعداد:"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:id="@+id/countName1"
                android:textColor="@color/app_black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="نام"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/textName1"
                android:textColor="@color/app_black"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- List items -->
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/returnedGoods"
        android:background="@drawable/nab_border_returned_goods"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/StolenGoods"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addReturnedButton"
                style="@style/MenuButtonsSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_plus" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="اجناس برگشتی"
                android:textColor="@color/app_black"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:background="#9FB4A0"
            android:id="@+id/linear3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="واحد:"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/unitName2"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/app_black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="تعداد:"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:id="@+id/countName2"
                android:textColor="@color/app_black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="نام"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/textName2"
                android:textColor="@color/app_black"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listReturnedContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

and its a image of my problem
enter image description here
I've tried various solutions such as using NestedScrollView and adjusting layout constraints, but haven't been successful in ensuring that the bottom buttons remain visible at all times while allowing the RecyclerViews to scroll independently.
Could someone provide guidance on how to properly structure the layout to ensure that the bottom buttons always remain visible in the main tab fragment, even when the RecyclerViews are populated with data and scrolling? Any code snippets or layout adjustments would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
